# Insert node into Dllist

Tags: c, algorithm, list, data-structures, doubly-linked-list

I'm trying to insert a node into a doubly linked list using a procedure instead of a function that returns a pointer to the new head of the list.

I'm getting this compiler error:

```
struct.c: In function 'insert':
struct.c:28:10: error: '*head' is a pointer; did you mean to use '->'?
     *head->prev = new_node;
          ^~
          ->
```

code:

```
typedef struct node {
    int val;
    struct node* next;
    struct node* prev;
}node;

void insert(node** head, int val) {
    node* new_node = malloc(sizeof(node));
    new_node->val = val;
    new_node->next = *head;
    *head->prev = new_node;
    *head = new_node;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you mean

```
( *head )->prev = new_node;
```

instead of

```
*head->prev = new_node;
```

because the postfix operator `->` has a higher precedence than the unary operator `*` and you need at first to dereference the pointer `head` before applying the operator ->.

Nevertheless the function in any case is wrong. If you declared only a head of the list (though usually a head and a tail node are declared for doubly-linked lists) then the function should be implemented like

```
void insert( node** head, int val ) 
{
    node *new_node = malloc( sizeof( node ) );

    new_node->val = val;
    new_node->next = *head;
    new_node->prev = NULL;

    if ( *head ) ( *head )->prev = new_node;

    *head = new_node;
}
```

Or it is better to define it such a way that it would return a signal whether the operation was successfull.

For example

```
int insert( node** head, int val ) 
{
    node *new_node = malloc( sizeof( node ) );
    int success = new_node != NULL;

    if ( success )
    {
        new_node->val = val;
        new_node->next = *head;
        new_node->prev = NULL;

        if ( *head ) ( *head )->prev = new_node;

        *head = new_node;
    }

    return success;
}
```

Comment: yeah I forgot the case where the list is empty and head is pointing to null, thanks!

Comment: @PrOoOg And you also forgot that the member prev_node of new_node also shall be set to NULL.:)

Answer (score 0):

*I'm getting this compiler error:*  ? Its because of operator precedence(as  `->` having higher priority than `*` so it performs first `head->` which you don't want, you want first `*head` to happen, so put `(*head)`.

`*head->prev` should be `(*head)->prev`.

```
(*head)->prev = new_node;
```

As pointed by others, do proper validation(check all test cases).

```
    if((*head) == NULL) { /* for first node */
              new_node->prev = 0; /* for first node prev should 0 */
              new_node->next = *head;
              *head = new_node;
              return 1;
    }
    else {
             new_node->next = *head;
             (*head)->prev = *head; /*otherwise head content */
             *head = new_node;
   }
```

Comment: @PrOoOg It is not a full answer. Your function has other problems. See my answer.